# How do you determine the rank of the differential of an immersion?

Tags: manifolds, matrix-rank, differential, tensor-rank

I'm trying to prove that some mapping of a manifold is also a manifold using the constant rank theorem but I don't really understand the meaning of rank in this context.

As I understand it, the prescription is as follows:

Let M be a manifold with local coordinates $(x^1 \dots x^m)$

Let $\theta:M\rightarrow N$ be an immersion:

$\theta(x^1 \dots x^m) = (y^1 \dots y^n)$

Then N is a manifold if $d\theta = \frac{\partial\theta}{\partial x^1} dx^1 \dots \frac{\partial\theta}{\partial x^n} dx^n $

has constant rank.

This has something to do with ensuring a constant number of elements of the $\frac{\partial\theta}{\partial x^i}$'s are linearly independent I think? and usually has something to do with making sure they don't evaluate to 0's in the domain.

Essentially, if someone could tell me how to calculate rank in this situation, identify cases where it changes so we don't have a manifold and/or correct anything else I've misunderstood, that would be amazing. Examples would also be incredible as I can't find many online but no worries if not.

Thanks!

Comment: There are different ways to compute the rank of a linear map. See any basic linear algebra textbook

Comment: I've looked through several different explanations already but they were presented quite technically. Could you provide a simple explanation of one of the ways to do this? Thanks

Comment: This is because it is a technical question. An algorithm that always works is [Gauss' pivot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination)

Comment: (Of course, you need to find the matrix of the differential in some basis!)

Comment: Ok, so am I trying to calculate the matrix rank of the matrix A with entires $A_{i,j} = (\frac{\partial\theta}{\partial x^i})_j$?

Comment: If you write $\theta = (\theta_1,\ldots,\theta_m)$, then the matrix is $(\frac{\partial \theta_j}{\partial x^i})$. I think your $y_k$'s correspond to my $\theta_k$'s

Comment: Thanks, that's really helped my understanding